# Getting coordinates from shapefile

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I have a .shp file (downloaded from [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-coastline-for-analysis-1/gis-data/europe-coastline-shapefile)), but it is a bunch of pink lines (I expected something like a bunch of dots or something and I have to transform it into gps coordinates (which I guess it's a .gpx file), but I have a lot of trouble finding the tools to do so and understanding what everything means. Right now I'm using QGIS, and I think once I have the coordinates I should dump the values into PostGIS. Could you guys point me in the right direction about which tools I should use, how or tips about how to do things the right way?

Further explanation: I want to get coordinate points that "shape" the coastline, so given a house's position, it can tell you how far away the coast is from the house.

Edit: I managed to get some stuff with QGIS "extract nodes" option, but I don't see any use for this data:

```
Shape_Leng,Shape_Area
309.72983208000,4079.18723489000
309.72983208000,4079.18723489000
```

Values repeat a lot and they don't look like map coordinates. What went wrong?

Comment: why were you expecting a coastline to be dots and not a line?

Comment: @iant Because I have absolutely no idea about how anything of this works. Thanks for the typo edits, by the way!

Comment: may be you could add a higher level description of what you are trying to do and we could give better advice

Comment: @iant done! I hope this is better,

Comment: Please see the edits to my answer based on these comments

Comment: @iant The duplicate doesn't have anything to do with what I want...

Comment: if all you want is the distance from houses to the coast then that question is the one you want

Comment: @iant I want the coordinates to put on the database.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @Newwt. Except Newwt shouldn't tag things with `qgis` when his question clearly calls for PostGIS.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm using (or trying to use) qgis too, so I used the tag to inform about it. Sorry, I'll remove it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the vertices go `Vector->Geometry Tools->Extract nodes`.

However, if you want to simply import a shapefile into PostGIS you can do it in one go (you don't ***have*** to convert to points unless you want to).  Use [shp2pgsql](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg).  This tool will be helpful whether you want the points or the lines.  Do a search on this site for more information on both topics here.

**EDIT:**
Following the comments above, have a look [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_data.html) to get you started on 'how things work'.  Also - for your situation you will want the line, so do ***not*** extract just the points.  So simply use shp2pgsql to load your shapefile into postgis.  That's all you need to do.  Then in PostGIS, ensure you have a spatial index

```
CREATE INDEX coastline_gidx on coastline USING GIST(geometry)
```

Then, depending on your exact use-case, consider using [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) or [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) to test for the distance (other distance tools are also available so check the documentation).

Comment: I just did the `shp2pgsql` thing, but it generates an empty sql file (if I use `shp2pgsql -s 4236 -I Europe_coastline.shp coastline > coastline.sql`), or a table-less database.

Comment: You may need to specify LATIN1 as the encoding.  Personally, I'd recommend the GUI for a beginner, rather than the commandline and it will load the data directly into the DB without making an intermediary sql file.  But see the link I added above for commandline options to help you with the encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

This question breaks down into a few questions questions,

1. How do I geocode to get a coordinate-POINT from a house's position?
2. Given an arbitrary POINT and a LINESTRING, what is the nearest point on the string?

   This is answered simply with a `ST_Line_Locate_Point` followed by a call to `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point`.
3. Given two points how do I find the distance between them?

   This is answered with a simple call to `ST_Distance(pt1::geography, pt2::geography)`.